# Driver fails on every restart. (Code 37)

Tags: windows-7, drivers, reboot

I have encountered the following problem:

Every time I restart the machine built-in smartcard reader becomes inaccessible with the following error:

> Windows cannot initialize the device driver for this hardware. (Code 37)

If I uninstall the device in the Device Manager, windows successfully installs it and the card reader is available again... until the next restart. This is of course very frustrating, I don't like the idea of having to install the driver every time I log on.

Any ideas how to fix this behavior?

- OS: Windows-7 pro x64
- Device: Microsoft Usbccid Smartcard Reader (WUDF)

### Error screenshot:

[image]

### After re-installing the driver:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Any additional related events in System event log?

Comment: Did you check this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/978977 ?

Comment: There is no option to delete driver when uninstalling. System log is disabled by group policy.
Hotfix from microsofr I have tried, but keep getting:"_The update is not applicable to your computer_" message

Comment: You mean that you can install/uninstall driver like local admin, but GPO disables you the event log access? That is a strange setup indeed, but some admin will be able to read the log surely.

Comment: Try to run `sc CONFIG wudfsvc start= auto`

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal, That did it! Or a combination of the above. Either way, the problem is now solved. Thanks++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you looked to the System event log, you would probably find a message like this:

> Source: Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode
>   Description: The
>   UMDF reflector was unable to complete startup because the WUDFSvc
>   service was not found. This service may be started later during boot,
>   at which point Windows will attempt to start the device again.

The similar problem is [described in this Microsoft support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/978977), though this hotfix is already quite old and probably you have already installed it as a part of regular Windows updates.

Your Smartcard driver did not start because [the User-Mode Driver Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Driver_Frameworks) service did not start on demand.

As a workaround you can try to change the `wudfsvc` service to start automatically on startup using this command:

```
sc CONFIG wudfsvc start= auto
```